# Better way implementation of two master pages in asp .net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, master-pages

In my project(website) I have two master pages. The only difference between them is, one have sidebar and other does not. Except sidebar, header/footer and all other things are same.

All is working well, but issue arises when I have to make changes in header / footer. I have to do it two time seperatly on both master pages which sometime creates confussion.

Can anyone tell me the better way to implement this, so that I have to make changes only once.

Comment: You can [nest master pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks, I will now nest my master pages

Comment: You could either nest them or use custom `UserControls` that you drop on both masterpages. If you then change the logic or layout of the `UserControl` you'll change it for all `MasterPages`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter please give me link of webpage explaining this technique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Master pages can be nested. So you could have master page A, and then B and C both reference A. Or you could have master page A, with just B referencing it. You'll have to examine your code and see which one will work best for your situation.

Below example [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7(v=vs.140).aspx), demonstrating a single parent master page and a single child.

Parent:

```
<% @ Master Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 
    1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<div>
<h1>Parent Master</h1>
<p style="font:color=red">This is parent master content.</p>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Child:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Parent.master"%> 
<asp:Content id="Content1" ContentPlaceholderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   <asp:panel runat="server" id="panelMain" backcolor="lightyellow">
   <h2>Child master</h2>
      <asp:panel runat="server" id="panel1" backcolor="lightblue">
        <p>This is child master content.</p>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ChildContent1" runat="server" />
      </asp:panel>
      <asp:panel runat="server" id="panel2" backcolor="pink">
         <p>This is child master content.</p>
         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ChildContent2" runat="server" />
      </asp:panel>
      <br />
   </asp:panel>
</asp:Content>
```